# Can i make an md-dialog dragable?

Tags: angularjs

i have been wondering if it's possible to make an `<md-dialog>` drag-able by user.. (in angular for web) 
i looked around but haven't find anything substantial on this subject

this is the overall structure..

```
<md-dialog>
    <form>
        <header></header>
        <md-subheader>
            <div>
            <md-select>
                <md-select-label>
                </md-select-label>
                <md-options>
                </md-options>
            </md-select>
            </div>
        </md-subheader>
        <md-dialog-content>
            <div>
                <textarea>

                <textarea>
            </div>
            <md-button>
            </md-button>
        </md-dialog-content>

    </form>
</md-dialog>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can make draggable using a directive and apply to the md-dialog

Here is a sample,

```
<md-dialog   draggable>
```

**Directive**

```
routerApp.directive('draggable', function() {
    return {
        // A = attribute, E = Element, C = Class and M = HTML Comment
        restrict: 'A',
        //The link function is responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM.
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.draggable({
                stop: function(event, ui) {
                    console.log("Check if its printing")
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: this link explain this pretty good http://www.benfarrell.com/2013/03/30/drag-and-drop-with-angularjs-and-jquery-ui/

Comment: This works but for anyone also using angular drag & drop all you need to do is add the drag drop directives (i.e.  < md-dialog  data-drag="1" data-jqyoui-options     jqyoui-draggable="{animate:true}"...) .

Comment: TypeError: element.draggable is not a function